# How get access to the translated data before the runApp Function?

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, localizable.strings

I would like use translation in a NotificationLayer created before the `runApp` in my main file.

But EasyLocation is initialized after, in the runApp function.

How I can access to the translated data before the runApp Function ?

There is my main function:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Init App translations
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  // Init ble Application Layer.
  NotificationLayer().load();

  // Forcing orientation
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback((systemOverlaysAreVisible) async {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(AppTheme.systemUIOverlayStyle);
  });

  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en'), Locale('fr')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
      child: MyApp()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not to do like that, but you can try to get the translation for yourself reading `assets/translations` file and find whatever you want.